# Microsoft clarity script throwing error in React js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, analytics, clarity

I tried integrating the `Microsoft clarity` script tag in my react website using `Helmet` and the script tag is throwing an error. Even though it was copied from the Microsoft clarity website.

```
 `<script type="text/javascript">    
  (function(c,l,a,r,i,t,y){
      c[a]=c[a]||function(){(c[a].q=c[a].q||[]).push(arguments)};
      t=l.createElement(r);
      t.async=1;
      t.src="https://www.clarity.ms/tag/"+i;
      y=l.getElementsByTagName(r)[0];
      y.parentNode.insertBefore(t,y);
  })(window, document, "clarity", "script", "7ds6fq93fz");
 </script>`


  `Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected "}"
9 | <script type="text/javascript">
10 |     (function(c,l,a,r,i,t,y){
11 | c[a]=c[a]||function(){(c[a].q=c[a].q||[]).push(arguments)};
| ^
12 | t=l.createElement(r);
13 | t.async=1;
14 | t.src="https://www.clarity.ms/tag/"+i;eslint
'}' expected.ts(1005)`
```

My Code:

```
import React from "react";
import { Helmet } from "react-helmet";

class siteAnalytics extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="siteAnalytics">
                <Helmet>
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                        (function(c,l,a,r,i,t,y){
                            c[a] = c[a] || function () { (c[a].q = c[a].q || []).push(arguments) };
                        t=l.createElement(r);
                        t.async=1;
                        t.src="https://www.clarity.ms/tag/"+i;
                        y=l.getElementsByTagName(r)[0];
                        y.parentNode.insertBefore(t,y);
            })(window, document, "clarity", "script", "7ds6fq93fz");
                    </script>
                </Helmet>
            </div>
        );
    }
};

export default siteAnalytics;
```

Am I doing it wrong? or there is some issue with the script?

Answer (score 3):

You can not write javascript directly in `<script>` tag. 
You need to use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` attribute of React for this purpose.

```
<script
  dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
    __html: `
        (function(c,l,a,r,i,t,y){
            c[a] = c[a] || function () { (c[a].q = c[a].q || []).push(arguments) };
            t=l.createElement(r);
            t.async=1;
            t.src="https://www.clarity.ms/tag/"+i;
            y=l.getElementsByTagName(r)[0];
            y.parentNode.insertBefore(t,y);
        })(window, document, "clarity", "script", "7ds6fq93fz");`,
  }}
/>;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use react-microsoft-clarity package

`npm install react-microsoft-clarity --save`

and then for example import it in _app.js

`import { clarity } from 'react-microsoft-clarity';`

and use it in a useEffet hook in the App.js component with your id

`clarity.init(id);`

Comment: This is causing an error on mine. says `SyntaxError: The requested module 'react-microsoft-clarity' does not provide an export named 'clarity'`